# Inconsistent result when comparing Actions/Funcs

Tags: c#, comparison, func

I have been trying to cache the results of certain `Actions` and `Funcs`. 
For that purpose I am storing the `Actions`/`Funcs` in a `Dictionary` with their respective result.

Whilst doing this I stumbled upon something unexpected (example is simplified):

```
        var lstActions = new List<Action>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            lstActions.Add(() => { });
        }

        bool bEqual = lstActions[0] == lstActions[1]; // Result = true
```

--

```
        var lstActions = new List<Action>();

        lstActions.Add(() => { });
        lstActions.Add(() => { });

        bool bEqual = lstActions[0] == lstActions[1]; // Result = false
```

Can anyone explain why the results are different?

Comment: Why shouldn't they be different?

Comment: To me the code that adds the 2 actions in the for loop is the same as adding the 2 actions separately. So unless I am missing something they should be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing implementation details about how the compiler transforms lambda expressions into delegates that point to compiler-generated methods.

This behavior may change due to changes in the compiler, debug vs. release builds, or changes in the contents of any of the lambdas.

To explain your current behavior:

Every lambda that appears in source is compiled to a separate method.  Therefore, your second example generates two methods (which happen to have identical bodies), and the delegates are not the same.

Your first example only has one lambda *in the source*, so it compiles to a single method.  Because the lambda doesn't use any local variables, it doesn't generate a closure class, so the both the `Method` and `Target` properties of the delegates are the same.

Comment: I suspected that it was something like this. Thanks for clarifying, I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler tries to minimize the amount of `delegate` objects it creates. To this end it often caches instances where this is possible.

Since your first example you define a single lambda and it does not capture any loop variables, a single delegate instance will suffice.

In the second example, you defined two different anonymous methods, the compiler will not check that their code is identical as this is a rare case, and will create two delegate instances.

This is however an implementation detail of the compiler and I would not rely on it in any way.

Comment: Also thanks to you for your answer. Both your answer and @SLaks answer the question.

Comment: @Jens Yeah, we were both probably writing it at the same time and posted seconds apart :)